# Character encoding issues when reading XLS files with PHP

Tags: php, excel, character-encoding, xls, iconv

I'm using the [PHP-Excel-Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation) library to read some XLS files and immediately have hit this issue:

> PHP Notice:  `iconv()` [function.iconv]: Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in C:\web\docs\housing\excel_reader2.php on line 1718

The line in question is this:

```
$result = iconv('UTF-16LE', $this->_defaultEncoding, $string);
```

And I've added some debugging info before that to help diagnose the problem:

```
var_dump($string);                   // string(10) "A�r�i�a�l�"
echo bin2hex($string) . "\n";        // 41007200690061006c00
echo $this->_defaultEncoding . "\n"; // UTF-8
```

I've tried changing to the `_defaultEncoding` to any number of random charsets but it obviously hasn't helped.

If anyone has any clues, please do help!

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old post, but one thing to check is if there are any links in your excel file. I ran in to the exact same issue and it was solved by removing any hyperlinks from the excel file.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Removed the hyperlinks and everything was OK.

Comment: how to remove hyperlinks?

Answer (score 1):

since it is a warning you may ignore it try this:

$result = @iconv('UTF-16LE', $this->_defaultEncoding, $string);

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$result = iconv('UTF-16LE', $this->_defaultEncoding . "//IGNORE", $string);
```

Comment: can you give an example of your xls file